# How to modify a Texture pixels from a compute shader in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing, shader, texture2d, compute-shader

I stumbled upon a strange problem in vuforia.When i request a camera image using CameraDevice.GetCameraImage(mypixelformat), the image returned is both flipped sideways and rotated 180 deg. Because of this, to obtain a normal image i have to first rotate the image and then flip it sideways.The approach i am using is simply iterating over pixels of the image and modifying them.This approach is very poor performance wise.Below is the code:

```
    Texture2D image;

    CameraDevice cameraDevice = Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance;
    Vuforia.Image vufImage = cameraDevice.GetCameraImage(pixelFormat);
    image = new Texture2D(vufImage.Width, vufImage.Height);
    vufImage.CopyToTexture(image);

    Color32[] colors = image.GetPixels32();
    System.Array.Reverse(colors, 0, colors.Length);  //rotate 180deg
    image.SetPixels32(colors);                       //apply rotation
    image = FlipTexture(image);                      //flip sideways






                 //***** THE FLIP TEXTURE METHOD *******//

private Texture2D FlipTexture(Texture2D original, bool upSideDown = false)
{

    Texture2D flipped = new Texture2D(original.width, original.height);

    int width  = original.width;
    int height = original.height;


    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            if (upSideDown)
            {
                flipped.SetPixel(row, (width - 1) - col, original.GetPixel(row, col));
            }
            else
            {
                flipped.SetPixel((width - 1) - col, row, original.GetPixel(col, row));
            }
        }
    }

    flipped.Apply();

    return flipped;
}
```

To improve the performance i want to somehow schedule these pixel operations on the GPU, i have heard that a compute shader can be used, but i have no idea where to start.Can someone please help me write the same operations in a compute shader so that the GPU can handle them, Thankyou!.

Comment: The VuforiaConfiguration has an option to flip the camera image horizontally. might that option solve your problem?

Comment: That only flips the image when Vuforia play is enabled(In unity editor only)

Comment: And btw it doesn't work!.

Comment: May I ask how you want to use the Texture2D, and how to apply it?

Comment: I don't want to apply the texture onto anything, otherwise i would've just change the u v's and cancelled the flipping and rotation effect.I have a function that crops the part of the Texture2D passed to it, which comes under a RectTransform (Region of interest).Something similar to how the windows snipping tool is, except that my function crops from a texture passed to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole compute shader are new for me too, but i took the occasion to research it a little bit for myself too. The following works for flipping a texture vertically (rotating and flipping horizontally should be just a vertical flip). 
Someone might have a more elaborate solution for you, but maybe this is enough to get you started.

The Compute shader code:

```
 #pragma kernel CSMain
// Create a RenderTexture with enableRandomWrite flag and set it
// with cs.SetTexture
RWTexture2D<float4> Result;
Texture2D<float4> ImageInput;
float2 flip;
[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    flip = float2(512 , 1024) - id.xy ;
    Result[id.xy] = float4(ImageInput[flip].x, ImageInput[flip].y, ImageInput[flip].z, 1.0);
}
```

and called from any script:

```
public void FlipImage()
{
    int kernelHandle = shader.FindKernel("CSMain");
    RenderTexture tex = new RenderTexture(512, 1024, 24);
    tex.enableRandomWrite = true;
    tex.Create();

    shader.SetTexture(kernelHandle, "Result", tex);
    shader.SetTexture(kernelHandle, "ImageInput", myTexture);
    shader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, 512/8 , 1024 / 8, 1);

    RenderTexture.active = tex;
    result.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), 0, 0);
    result.Apply();
}
```

This takes an input Texture2D, flips it in the shader, applies it to a RenderTexture and to a Texture2D, whatever you need.
Note that the image sizes are hardcoded in my instance and should be replaced by whatever size you need. (for within the shader use shader.SetInt(); )